# how to place activity indicator in alert view when clicking button of that alert view

Tags: iphone

i am using the simple alert view with two buttons names as ok,cancel.

when ever i press ok,cancel alert view quits as general.

But i need when ever i click alert view ok button with out quit alert view activity indicator
will run for 2 min on the same alert view  and quit. when ever i click cancel it quits normally.

can any one please help me.

Thank u in advance.

Comment: why need do this? after alert view disappears, show an waiting view for a while.

Comment: when ever i click ok button i need to update the process that takes 2 min,thats why i need this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the UI control events for the OK button, so that your own event handler is called for that button and the alert view won't be dismissed until the long-running task has finished.
In that event handler attach an activity indicator to the view and start your task asynchronously using GCD.

```
#import <dispatch/dispatch.h>

// ...

UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK"    ,nil];

for (UIView *subview in alert.subviews)
{
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]] && subview.tag == 2) {
        UIControl* button = (UIControl*) subview;
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonOKPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button removeTarget:alert action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
    }
}
[alert show];
[alert release];

// ...

-(void) buttonOKPressed:(UIControl*) sender {

    [sender removeTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
    UIAlertView* alert = (UIAlertView*)[sender superview];
    CGRect alertFrame = alert.frame;
    UIActivityIndicatorView* activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(0,alertFrame.size.height, alertFrame.size.width,30);
    activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
    activityIndicator.alpha = 0.0;
    activityIndicator.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    [activityIndicator startAnimating]; 
    [alert addSubview:activityIndicator];
    [activityIndicator release];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        alert.frame = CGRectMake(alertFrame.origin.x, alertFrame.origin.y, alertFrame.size.width, alertFrame.size.height+50);
        activityIndicator.alpha = 1.0;

    }];         
    //alert.userInteractionEnabled = NO; // uncomment this, if you want to disable all buttons (cancel button)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5]; // replace this with your long-running task
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (alert && alert.visible) {
                [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:alert.firstOtherButtonIndex animated:YES];
            }
        });
    });
}
```